# How to place line labels underneath point symbols in QGIS 2.16.2?

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

I would like to make a map, where the street names are labeled but point symbols shouldn't be covered (see attached image). I learned from another post, that labels are always rendered last and that there is no way to change the rendering order. Is this still true?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have now an option "Discourage other labels from covering features in this layer" where you usually activate the labels. That you set as labeling option for your points(they don´t get labels, only the function is set there).

Comment: I tried to use this Option already but it has almost zero impact on the placement of the street names.